# How to secure the CM site in Sitecore?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8

I'm trying to lock down the CM (master) site. The users are going to have to login in order to view the site.

The config below gets added to sitecore.config. Unfortunately, the implementation below only works fro the homepage (e.g. /).
When an anonymous user goes to /hello-world, they'll see a "white" page that doesn't have any content. It doesn't direct them to the login page.

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/" xmlns:set="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/set/">
  <sitecore>
    <sites>
      <site name="website" 
              set:requireLogin="true" 
              set:domain="sitecore" 
              set:loginPage="/sitecore/login" 
              set:targetHostName="master.website.com" 
              set:scheme="http" />
    </sites>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

Visiting homepage takes me to 
[login page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i61OK.png)
But, if i manually enter an interior page URL, i get the following:
[white page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BU70P.png)

Comment: did you deny the read access to homepage and all his chiidren for extranet/anonymous user?

Comment: No. If i do, the smart publish will publish those settings to the production site. I need to isolate the CM (content management).

Comment: Your question is not very clear. CM comes from Content Management, so from your question I understand you are trying to secure the Sitecore CMS .. which is secured by default. I guess you want to enable login for a website, right?

Comment: No. I want to secure the CM site. CM is secured only if you go to the homepage. If you manually enter in any other page, you'll get a white page with no content.

Comment: It would be better to secure your CM environment using ACL (Access Control Lists) by restricting to certain IP Addresses or via VPN.

Comment: Hi. Is your site Webforms or MVC based?

There is a known bug in current Sitecore versions, where the requireLogin attribute does not get respected on MVC "pages" (pages that use an MVC layout).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further investigation, and contacting the sitecore community, I found out that there is a bug in sitecore 8 update 5 (mvc). The security check doesn't work properly.

Here is the FIX:
1. Add a pipeline that inherits from SecurityCheck.

```
public class SecurityCheck : Sitecore.Pipelines.RenderLayout.SecurityCheck
{
            private RequestBeginArgs originalArgs;

            public virtual void Process(RequestBeginArgs args)
            {
                originalArgs = args;
                Process(new RenderLayoutArgs((System.Web.UI.Page)new Sitecore.Web.UI.HtmlControls.Page(), (Item)null));
            }

            protected override bool HasAccess()
            {
                SiteContext site = Context.Site;
                if (site != null && site.RequireLogin && (!Context.User.IsAuthenticated && !this.IsLoginPageRequest()))
                {
                    originalArgs.AbortPipeline();
                    return false;
                }
                if (site == null || site.DisplayMode == DisplayMode.Normal || (Context.User.IsAuthenticated || !(PreviewManager.GetShellUser() == string.Empty)) || this.IsLoginPageRequest())
                    return true;
                originalArgs.AbortPipeline();
                return false;
            }
}
```

2. Add this processor as a first processor in the

```
<mvc.requestBegin>
    <!-- security check for site -->
    <processor type="Namespace.SecurityCheck, Assembly"/>
  </mvc.requestBegin>
```

Answer (score 0):

To make it work, only 2 settings should be changed for the "website" configuration node - `requireLogin` and `loginPage`. So you definitely set it correctly.
I met similar "blank page" issue in the past, it was related to some misconfiguration of the `ItemNotFoundUrl` setting. It could be your case as well, if the "hello-world" page doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try this:

```
<site name="website" virtualFolder="/" physicalFolder="/" rootPath="/sitecore/content" startItem="/hello-world" database="master" domain="extranet" allowDebug="true" cacheHtml="true" htmlCacheSize="10MB" registryCacheSize="0" viewStateCacheSize="0" xslCacheSize="5MB" filteredItemsCacheSize="2MB" enablePreview="true" enableWebEdit="true" enableDebugger="true" disableClientData="false" requireLogin="true" loginPage="/sitecore/login/Default.aspx" />
```

**Highlights:**

1. **startItem** : set to hello-world page (assuming this is the home item)
2. **database**  : set to master (depends on your test case(s), you can use *web* db, as well)
3. **loginPage** : redirect to Sitecore login page
4. **requireLogin** : enforce login, set to TRUE